# How to generate a dynamic report in java

Tags: java, hibernate, reporting-services

I am doing a project for a clinical laboratory. I am using java, hibernate and SQL Server for my project. In some cases I need to generate reports on results of the particular Lab tests, for each tests the format of report differs.It is impossible to create predesigned forms for all the tests. So in this case the freedom of designing the form for test report should be given to the user of the application and this report format is mapped to each tests, so that when the application runs the report should be generated dynamically according to the mapped report format of the test. Can anyone help me to suggest a method for doing this(Here the report format is designed by user by using drag and drop facility, because the user is not technically skilled to do it by coding.The designed form can be mapped to a particular test by the user and the report is generated according to the uploaded format by filling the data of particular test  taken from database). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server provides a reporting service component ([SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms159106.aspx)). Reports could be designed by the user in a desktop tool called [Business Intelligence Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767(v=sql.105).aspx)*. This tool allows the user to drag and drop UI components to generate a template file. The template file contains two important details - data source details to fetch data & the format of the report to be displayed.

The template file is then uploaded on the report server. A report is generated from this template dynamically when needed. Dynamically here refers to the fact that the data to be displayed in the report is fetched at runtime when the request for report generation is made.

The template file can also accept Report Parameters which could help to generate multiple variants of the report for one template file. There are various other SSRS features which you could browse [through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522683.aspx).

SSRS dynamically report generation capability seems to suit the requirements you mention above.

SSRS also has exposes [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) through you can integrate your application with SSRS. There are web service methods for uploading a template and rendering a report.

*There are web based alternatives too. One of them is [cizer](http://www.cizer.com/).

Comment: The application is basically written in java. Is it possible to integrate the templates with java?

Comment: Yes. You can do that through web services. Updated the answer too.

Comment: What if I am creating a desktop application.

Comment: Are you saying you desktop application cannot call SSRS web services? These web services are soap based web services. You need to use axis2 to generate stubs. Stubs are then used to make the web service calls. Here's one example - http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/how-to-integrate-java-with-microsoft_4178.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, helped me to form an idea.